# Automate text extraction using python

Tags: python-3.x, database, pandas, dataframe

I have bunch of documents in excel, pdf, docx, and they all have different shapes/layouts. I want to automate writing these documents in a database.

what I have been doing was to read them in pandas and process them manually. the PROBLEM is even excel files have different shapes and topics, like balance sheets, income statements, with heterogeneous dataframes. pdf can be bank statements, application forms, invoices etc.

What would be the best way to go about this using python?

Comment: Please note that SO is no place to ask "Do it for me". Please read the guidelines. Please do paste or updte your question with your efforts and research so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since the document types are varying you would want to use different ways of processing each type of document.

1. Excel Documents: You can read the excel sheets into a pandas data frame and then dump the records into the database by simple database queries. This [link](https://www.journaldev.com/33306/pandas-read_excel-reading-excel-file-in-python) should be helpful for this purpose.
2. PDF Documents: There quite a few utilities to extract text from PDF documents. [PyPDF](https://pypi.org/project/pyPdf/) and [pdfminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) are two libraries which should help you extract text from the PDF documents.
3. Image Documents: You can use [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) library for extracting text from images.

I hope it helps.

Comment: what I have been doing was to read them in pandas and process them manually. the PROBLEM is even excel files have different shapes and topics, like balance sheets, income statements, with heterogeneous dataframes. pdf can be bank statements, application forms, invoices etc.